# jquery detect nunber of item inside a div and add a class

Tags: jquery, children

I would like to add a style to a div if number of items within this div is >2

If number of `<ie:menuitem>` is more than 2 then set `div` with `id` of  `s4-ribbonrow` to  `display:block;`

```
<div class="s4-pr" id="s4-ribbonrow" style="height: 135px; display: none;">
<ie:menuitem menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem>
</div>
```

How would i do that in Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
var $row = $('#s4-ribbonrow');

if ($row.children().length > 2)
    $row.css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: is there a way to identify precisely <ie:menuitem>?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by 'identify precisely'?  If you want to loop through the items you could do: `$row.children().each(function() { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var ribbon = $('#s4-ribbonrow'),
    menuitems = ribbon.children().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeName = 'IE:MENUITEM';
    });

if (menuitems.length>2){
    ribbon.show();
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mQaBQ/